# How see .doc/.docx and .pdf preview in a flutter mobile app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

the question is this. I have a list of documents retrieved from an api (jpg, doc, pdf) that come to me in binary format (unit8list). How do I preview doc and pdf files? For images I have already solved using MemoryImage () but I don't know which library or widget to use for .doc / .docx and pdf files. Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `open_file` package to open and view files.
Here is the URL. Check this out :)
https://pub.dev/packages/open_file

Comment: thanks, only that I have read on the net that this library needs the path of the file but the file is not present in the local memory but I map it into an object. How could I solve?

Answer (score 0):

The following package should work perfectly for displaying .pdf files: https://pub.dev/packages/advance_pdf_viewer. You can open any file with https://pub.dev/packages/open_file

Comment: thanks, only that I have read on the net that this library needs the path of the file but the file is not present in the local memory but I map it into an object. How could I solve?

Comment: @S.Miccio you could either save the file temporarily, or just use the viewer, that displays a pdf file without a path (e.g. from a File object)